# How to print the MST trees for every node of a graph?

Tags: graph, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I'm learning data structures and now I'm at Prim's algorithm. I want to modify the following algorithm to print the MST trees for every node of the graph or at least for a specified node but I don't really know from where to start.

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
int minKey(int key[], bool mstSet[])
{
    // Initialize min value  
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        if (mstSet[v] == false && key[v] < min)
            min = key[v], min_index = v;

    return min_index;
}
```

```
// function to print the constructed MST   
void printMST(int parent[], int graph[V][V])
{
    cout << "Edge \tWeight\n";
    for (int i = 1; i < V; i++)
        cout << parent[i] << " - " << i << " \t" << graph[i][parent[i]] << " \n";
}
```

```
void primMST(int graph[V][V])
{ 
    int parent[V];

    // Key values used to pick minimum weight edge  
    int key[V];

    // To represent set of vertices not yet included in MST  
    bool mstSet[V];

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        key[i] = INT_MAX, mstSet[i] = false;

    // Make key 0 so that this vertex is picked as first vertex.  
    key[0] = 0;
    parent[0] = -1; // First node is always root of MST  

    for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++)
    {
        // Pick the minimum key vertex 
        int u = minKey(key, mstSet);

        // Add the picked vertex to the MST Set  
        mstSet[u] = true;

        // Update key value and parent index of  
        // the adjacent vertices of the picked vertex.   
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)   
            if (graph[u][v] && mstSet[v] == false && graph[u][v] < key[v])
                parent[v] = u, key[v] = graph[u][v];
    }

    printMST(parent, graph);
}
```

Comment: The function `printMST` you provided seems to print the edges of the MST as expected. So I don't understand what you are asking for. Please clarify.